# GCC -flto changing symbol visibility

Tags: c++, c, gcc, optimization, compilation

I have a large piece of code, which produces errors when compiled using `-flto` only on some versions of gcc.  I will try to summarise below

in file1.h

```
extern char A [100];
```

in file1.c

```
#include "file1.h"
char A[100];
```

I also have some c++ code that uses the variable `A`.  The C++ code is compiled to an `.o` file, and then the whole thing is compiled with something like

```
gcc file1.c cpp.o
```

Using the version of gcc on archlinux (5.2.0), there is no problem both with and without `-flto`.  However using gcc on Ubuntu 14.04 (4.8.4), when the code is compiled with `-flto`, `A` becomes a local variable.  I have verified this with nm:

These are the output from `nm a.out` for the variable in question

Ubuntu, no lto (arch similar, with a different number):

```
00000000006162e0 B A
```

Ubuntu, lto

```
00000000006092c0 b A.2722
```

My understanding is that the `B` is for a global variable, and `b` is not.

How can I ensure that `A` is maintained as a global variable even when I use `-flto` on Ubuntu?

Comment: Is updating your compiler an option?  How about a separate object file a.o that contains the `char a[100];` buffer, with all others using it  `extern`?

Comment: Does the program work as desired on Ubuntu? Did you test it or are you just inspecting the symbol tables?

Comment: @idmean The program definitely fails on Ubuntu when it is run with a symbol lookup error

Comment: @technosaurus - I am distributing the code to other people, so the standard Ubuntu compiler working would be good.  The idea about the separate .o file is good and I will try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [this](https://trac.mplayerhq.hu/ticket/1695) and [this](https://answers.launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/+question/261316), it most certainly appears to be a bug within the particular version of gcc that you are using (gcc 4.8.4 comes bundled with Ubuntu 14.04).

Using the code snippets from the question,
i was able to reproduce the behaviour on my machine running Ubuntu 14.04.

> A simple workaround for this is to **explicitly mark the symbol in question as `used`**.

**`file1.c`** has `char A[100];`

**`file2.c`** has `__attribute__((used)) char A[100];`

```
gcc file1.c -o file1-default.o
nm file1-default.o | grep "A$"
0000000000601060 B A               <-- symbol is a global.

gcc file1.c -flto -o file1-flto.o
nm file1-flto.o | grep "A$"
0000000000601060 b A.2385          <-- symbol updated to a local.

gcc file2.c -flto -o file2.o
nm file2.o | grep "A$"
0000000000601060 B A               <-- symbol retained as global.
```